# How to send Message Disposition Notification Email in node.js or C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, email

I'm including a mail client in a software, and need to manage the "acknowledgment of receipt" sent with some e-mails.

Asking for one is simple, and implemented by the majority of librairies. What I'm searching is a way to (easily) generate an MDN mail in accordance to the standard defined here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798#section-2.1, to reply to "read receipt" requests.

My software is in C#/.NET, and (for reasons) the e-mails are sent by a server in Node.js.

I could read and implement the standard by myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I would like to know if a free library exists, in Node.js or in C#/.NET, allowing to automatically create an MDN mail. Alternatively, a good "How to" tutorial would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help !

**Edit :**

I can't use the default behaviour of my mail server. I'm using my mailbox as a "buffer" : every mail I receive is processed and deleted from the mail server by my own custom server.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky thing and depended from  email server settings.
You could use cross-platform ImapClient:

http://www.imapx.org/

for extracting email notification from your email box in you application code . Your email server should support sending receive notification messages.
You can add custom data in header emails and extract it from notification body for distinguishing what exactly was pontificated.

for all types protocols  you could use that (.Net):

https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=18

But the main idea remains the same - your system processes notification email from your email-box.

Comment: Asking the IMAP server to send the MDN could have been a great idea, unfortunately this can't be done with my configuration : I'm using POP3 to use my mail server as a "buffer". The e-mails are automatically removed from the server, and then processed, saved, and used by my application. 
In addition, I can't presume the mail server settings, as my software needs to be able to work with (theoretically) all mail servers ...

Comment: Not all email servers support notification feature. But your service  could remove processed emails from your email server instead automatically removing.

Comment: That's already what I'm doing (in my node.js server, but same thing). The problem here is that the acknowledgement needs to be user-initiated : I don't want to wait for the users to accept it to delete the mail from the server. And what if they don't ?

Comment: You should not wait  - you could delete messages from your email-box and notifications are income to your email box too. And user does not  approve notification : email server sends them  automatically

Comment: I don't want my server to send read receipts automatically. It can lead to enhanced spam issues : the spammer knows that the address is owned. 
I don't think I can do something else than simply create a MDN entirely.

Comment: You could substitute email sender (From)  and  receive  messages to your real email sender  address. But I got your point - probably real email can be extracted from email header.